# install4j patch(Add-on installer)

Tags: install4j

Is there a way to back out the add-on installer and retrieve the machine to the previous state automatically. I read that the is no uninstall action for add-on installer, so the answer might be no.

Will add-on installer use the same response file?

If new panels are added/removed in the add-on will the corresponding variable be added/removed in the response file?

Can we have multiple add-on installers for a single application-id?

`getAddOnApplicationInfoByDir()` What info it would be retrieving? 
As i see that version or application-id we don't modify for the add-on was curious how different add-on s are distinguished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to back out the add-on installer and retrieve the machine to 
>   the previous state automatically.

No, there is no way to do that.

> Will add-on installer use the same response file?

Yes, that's simply the "Load a response file" action in the installer.

> If new panels are added/removed in the add-on will the corresponding 
>   variable be added/removed in the response file?

No, the add-on installer will not overwrite the response file.

> getAddOnApplicationInfoByDir() What info it would be retrieving?

It returns all add-on installers that have been installed.

Comment: I see that getAddOnApplicationInfoByDir returns any array, by which i assume that we can have multiple add-on Installers.  I created a sample application with version 3.5 and add-on installer 3.6 and 3.7. After applying 3.6 and 3.7. I see that  getAddOnApplicationInfoByDir() is returning only the latest 3.7 information. Is there a way to retreive info all the add-on  installers?

Comment: If two add-on-installers have the same application ID, only the last one will be listed

Comment: Say a patch is meant to fix something in component1 and a patch for component2.  And applying the patch multiple times is not allowed. In such a scenario. I would be interested to know what all addon (patch) installers the user has run to say whether it is allowed to install the add-on or not. So is there a way to achieve this patchin process

Comment: Add-on installers are not good for delivering patches, the don't even set the installed version number. install4j does not have patch functionality at this point, but it's planned for a future version.